# Moving one div next to multiple divs (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have the following webpage:
[image]

I am trying to move the bottom-left, red-bordered div to the drawn red box.
(Next to main content, 3.5% right margin)

My code doesnt seem to be working no matter what though.

```css
body {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:#FFFFF0;
}

.cap {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.p {
    color:#37FDFC;
    max-height:inherit;
}

#container {
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#F6F4F1;
    border: 5px solid #00b4b4;
    padding:0;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#header {
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}

#header p {
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:3%;
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    color:#838B8B;
    font-family:verdana;
}

#footer:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.register_form {
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 4px solid #C1CDCD;
    width:70%;
}

#register_form {
    margin-left:4%;
    border-right: 2px dotted #00CDCD;
    width:30%;
    margin-right:0%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#register_form h2 {
    color:#00CDCD;
    font-family:verdana;
}

#side_text {
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    margin-right:30%;
}

#side_text h3 {
    color:#00CDCD;
    font-family:verdana;
}

#side_text p {
    color:#838B8B;
    font-family:verdana;
}

#login_form {
    margin-left:4%;
    border-right: 2px dotted #00CDCD;
    width:30%;
    margin-right:0%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#login_form h2 {
    color:#00CDCD;
    font-family:verdana;
}

.login_form {
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 4px solid #C1CDCD;
    width:70%;
}

#just_registered_text {
    text-align:center;
    color:#00CDCD;
    font-family:verdana;
}

#errors {
    float: left;
    margin-left:4.5%;
    text-align:left;
    color:red;
}

#other {
    float: right;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:3%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#profile_name_div {
    margin-left:3%;
    color: #00b4b4;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight: 700;
    display:inline;
}

#change_settings a {
    margin-left:5%;
    color:lightblue;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#settings_space h2 {
    margin-left:3%;
    color:#00CDCD;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#settings_space textarea {
    overflow: hidden; 
    resize: none;
    border: 2px solid #00CDCD; 
    margin-left:3%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#settings_space:first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

#settings_space label {
    margin-left:8%;
    color: #009acd;
}

.settings_submit {
    margin-left:5%;
}

.info {
    margin-left:3%;
    display:inline;
    color:#838B8B;
    font-family:verdana;
    width:100%;
}

#photo {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:3.5%;
}

#actual_photo {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

#change_pp {
    background:#f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
    border-top: 1px dashed #ccc;
    border-left: 1px dashed #ccc;
    border-right: 1px dashed #ccc;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:3.5%;
    padding:0;
}

#proj {
    display: none;
}

#button {
    width:100%;
}

#change_pp input[type=file] {
    width:100%;
}

.info > b {
    color:#00CDCD;
}

#about_me_header {
    margin-left:3.5%;
    color:#B4CDCD;
    border: 5px solid #00b4b4;
    border-radius:20px;
    width:50%;
}

#about_section {
    border:2px solid red;
    width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='header'>
        <p>The current date is $date:</p>
    </div>
    <span id="profile_name_div"> example </span>
    <span id="change_settings"> 
        <a href='account_settings.php'>Change Settings</a> 
    </span>
    <div id="photo">example</div>
    <div id="change_pp">    
        <button id="button" onclick="showForm()" >Change Profile Picture</button>
        <form  id="proj" action="include/form_handle.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" value="change" name="pp_file"/>
            <input type="submit" name="pp_submit" value="Upload Photo"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="about_section">    
        <h1 id="about_me_header">About me header</h1>
        <br/>
        <div class="info"><b>Bio: </b>text</div>
        <br/><br/>        
        <div class="info"><b>Interests: </b>text</div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div class="info"><b>Favorite Quotes: </b>text</div>
        <div id='footer'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/8jczhzaL/2/

- I have tried floating divs and nothing works.

How can I move my div next to the other divs to the left? And why doesnt floating work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave your left content a wrapper and floated it left. This should be pretty close to what you're looking for - just change some of the margins to get everything to line up exactly how you want it:

**Live Demo:**

```css
     body {
         margin-top:20px;
         margin-right:0;
         margin-left:0;
         margin-bottom:0;
         overflow: auto;
         background-color:#FFFFF0;
     }
     .cap {
         text-transform: capitalize;
     }
     .p {
         color:#37FDFC;
         max-height:inherit;
     }
     #container {
         width:90%;
         margin:auto;
         background-color:#F6F4F1;
         border: 5px solid #00b4b4;
         padding:0;
         border-radius: 25px;
     }
     #header {
         width:100%;
         top:0;
     }
     #header p {
         text-align:right;
         margin-right:3%;
     }
     #footer {
         width:100%;
         bottom:0;
         color:#838B8B;
         font-family:verdana;
     }
     #footer:after {
         content:"";
         clear: both;
         display: table;
     }
     .register_form {
         border-radius: 6px;
         border: 4px solid #C1CDCD;
         width:70%;
     }
     #register_form {
         margin-left:4%;
         border-right: 2px dotted #00CDCD;
         width:30%;
         margin-right:0%;
         display:inline-block;
     }
     #register_form h2 {
         color:#00CDCD;
         font-family:verdana;
     }
     #side_text {
         width:30%;
         float:right;
         margin-right:30%;
     }
     #side_text h3 {
         color:#00CDCD;
         font-family:verdana;
     }
     #side_text p {
         color:#838B8B;
         font-family:verdana;
     }
     #login_form {
         margin-left:4%;
         border-right: 2px dotted #00CDCD;
         width:30%;
         margin-right:0%;
         display:inline-block;
     }
     #login_form h2 {
         color:#00CDCD;
         font-family:verdana;
     }
     .login_form {
         border-radius: 6px;
         border: 4px solid #C1CDCD;
         width:70%;
     }
     #just_registered_text {
         text-align:center;
         color:#00CDCD;
         font-family:verdana;
     }
     #errors {
         float: left;
         margin-left:4.5%;
         text-align:left;
         color:red;
     }
     #other {
         float: right;
         text-align:right;
         margin-right:3%;
         display:inline-block;
     }
     #profile_name_div {
         margin-left:3%;
         color: #00b4b4;
         font-size: 27px;
         font-family:verdana;
         font-weight: 700;
         display:inline;
     }
     #change_settings a {
         margin-left:5%;
         color:lightblue;
         font-size: 16px;
         font-family:verdana;
         font-weight: 700;
     }
     #settings_space h2 {
         margin-left:3%;
         color:#00CDCD;
         font-size: 27px;
         font-family:verdana;
         font-weight: 700;
     }
     #settings_space textarea {
         overflow: hidden;
         resize: none;
         border: 2px solid #00CDCD;
         margin-left:3%;
         border-radius: 8px;
     }
     #settings_space:first-letter {
         text-transform: capitalize;
     }
     #settings_space label {
         margin-left:8%;
         color: #009acd;
     }
     .settings_submit {
         margin-left:5%;
     }
     .info {
         margin-left:3%;
         display:inline;
         color:#838B8B;
         font-family:verdana;
         width:100%;
     }
     #photo {
         display:block;
         border: 1px solid black;
         width:200px;
         height:200px;
         margin-left:3.5%;
     }
     #actual_photo {
         width:200px;
         height:200px;
     }
     #change_pp {
         background:#f9f9f9;
         border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
         border-top: 1px dashed #ccc;
         border-left: 1px dashed #ccc;
         border-right: 1px dashed #ccc;
         width:200px;
         margin-left:3.5%;
         padding:0;
     }
     #proj {
         display: none;
     }
     #button {
         width:100%;
     }
     #change_pp input[type=file] {
         width:100%;
     }
     .info > b {
         color:#00CDCD;
     }
     #about_me_header {
         margin-left:3.5%;
         color:#B4CDCD;
         border: 5px solid #00b4b4;
         border-radius:20px;
         width:50%;
     }
     #about_section {
         border:2px solid red;
         width:30%;
         float: right;
     }
#left_section {
 float: left;   
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='header'>
            <p>The current date is $date:</p>
        </div> <span id="profile_name_div"> example </span>
 <span id="change_settings"> 
 <a href='account_settings.php'>Change Settings
 </a> <br />
 </span>
        <div id="left_section">
        <div id="photo">example</div>
        <div id="change_pp">
            <button id="button" onclick="showForm()">Change Profile Picture</button>
            <form id="proj" action="include/form_handle.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" value="change" name="pp_file" />
                <input type="submit" name="pp_submit" value="Upload Photo" />
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="about_section">
             <h1 id="about_me_header">About me header</h1>

            <br/>
            <div class="info"><b>Bio: </b>text</div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div class="info"><b>Interests: </b>text</div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div class="info"><b>Favorite Quotes: </b>text</div>
            <div id='footer'></div>
            
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/8jczhzaL/3/